# How to unit test NestJs http request with full coverage?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am having trouble to test my NestJs Service. I wrote a method, which does a GET http request:

```
getEntries(): Observable<Entries[]> {
    Logger.log(`requesting GET: ${this.apiHost}${HREF.entries}`);
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiHost}${HREF.entries}`).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        return throwError(error);
      }),
      map(response => response.data)
    );
  }
```

I want to write a unit test for this method. This unit test should cover all lines of this method.
I tried to use "nock" package to mock this http request, but no matter how i try the coverage result is always the same.

```
return throwError(error);

map(response => response.data);
```

This two lines were uncovered.

Here my test file:

```
describe('getEntries method', () => {
    it('should do get request and return entries', () => {
      nock('http://localhost:3000')
        .get('/v1/entries')
        .reply(200, {
          data: require('../mocks/entries.json')
        });
      try {
        const result = service.getEntries();
        result.subscribe(res => {
          expect(res).toEqual(require('../mocks/entries.json'));
        });
      } catch (e) {
        expect(e).toBeUndefined();
      }
    });
    it('should return error if request failed', () => {
      nock('http://localhost:3000')
        .get('/v1/entries')
        .replyWithError('request failed');
      service.getEntries().subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).toBeUndefined();
      }, err => {
        expect(err).toBe('request failed');
      })
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used `nock` in the past, but you can just tell the `HttpService` what to respond with when using `jest.spyOn`. The biggest thing to remember is that the return is "synchronous", because it is a return of an observable. For testing your positive case, you can do something like

```js
it('should do the request and get the entries', (done) => {
  const httpSpy = jest.spyOn(httpService, 'get')
    .mockReturnValue(of({data: require('../mocks/entries.json')}))
  let data = {};
  service.getEntires().subscribe({
    next: (val) => {data = val},
    error: (err) => { throw error; }
    complete: () => {
      expect(data).toEqual(require('../mocks/entries.json'))
      done();
    }
});
```

And similarly, for the error route, you could use the `throwError()` operator.

Both `of` and `throwError` are imported from `rxjs`. The only thing to note is that with this method, you do need to get the `HttpService` from the current module context, similarly to how you would get any other service. Just making sure to call that out.

Comment: Thank your, i posted a few Changes.

Comment: Any way to do so for `post`?

Comment: `jest.spyOn(httpService, 'post')...` most of it follows as you'd expect. It's just another method on the `HttpService`

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for your reply. The code works fundamentally. I had to make a few changes for the test to work. Here are my changes:

```
describe('getEntries method', () => {
    it('should do get request and return entries', (done) => {
      jest.spyOn(service['http'], 'get').mockReturnValue(of({data: require('../mocks/entries.json'), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {}, config: {}}));
      let data = {};

      service.getEntries().subscribe({
        next: (val) => {data = val},
        error: (err) => { throw err; },
        complete: () => {
          expect(data).toEqual(require('../mocks/entries.json'))
          done();
        }
      });
    });
    it('should return error if request failed', (done) => {
      jest.spyOn(service['http'], 'get').mockReturnValue(throwError('request failed'));
      let data = {};

      service.getEntries().subscribe({
        next: (val) => {data = val},
        error: (err) => {
          expect(err).toBe('request failed');
          done();
        },
        complete: () => {
          expect(data).toBeUndefined();
          done();
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

You have to mock AxiosReponse on httpSpy mockReturnValue, so i added 'status', 'statusText', 'header', 'config'. Otherwise you will get a type error.

And second part. I was spying on httpService like this:

```
let httpService: HttpService;
httpService = module.get(HttpService)
```

This doesn't work. I have to spy on the HttpService injection of my Service.

```
constructor(private readonly http: HttpService) {}
```

That' why my spy looks like: service['http'].

Now i have full coverage on this http request :)

Thank you so much ;)
Have a nice day!